# I am using UseEffect Hook, but still component is getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null. in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to give a hover effect to a certain element that has an id "address-instructions".
I have used UseEffect so that it is only accessed after being rendered,  but I still get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onmouseover')
, which indicates that the component is not rendering.
Please help. Thank you in advance.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    document.getElementById("address-i").onmouseover = () => {
      document.getElementById("address-instructions").style.display = "block";
    };
  
    document.getElementById("address-i").onmouseout = () => {
      document.getElementById("address-instructions").style.display = "none";
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. `document.getElementById(address-i)` returns null. Are you sure it exists? Also, DOM manipulation is discouraged in React, unless you really _really_ have to.

Comment: `#address-instructions:hover { ... }`

Comment: @SinanYaman I'm sure it exists. I want to display an overlay text on hover, but I'm getting this error. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-http-m95ks2?file=/src/App.js) example.  As @Andreas suggested, using css pseudo-class is a better solution.

Comment: Moreover, your code [works in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-wind-qzhrmi?file=/src/App.js). So something is wrong with your ids and html. Yet again, this is bad practice.

Comment: Got it. I tried to add pseudoclass to an element that was before the selected element. It's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **useRef** for the same...

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const h2 = useRef();
  const hideElement = (ref) => {
    ref.current.style.display = "none";
  };
  const visibleElement = (ref) => {
    ref.current.style.display = "block";
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1
        onMouseOver={hideElement.bind(this, h2)}
        onMouseOut={visibleElement.bind(this, h2)}
      >
        Hello CodeSandbox
      </h1>
      <h2 ref={h2}>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can use above code directly on **codesandbox**.

I hope this will help you! **Happy coding...**